# According to the Catholic Church, does any child have the "right" to be baptized?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, papal-magisterium

The Church, echoing the affirmation of the LORD himself, teaches that  Baptism is necessary for salvation.<sup>1</sup>

Furthermore, parents are obliged to take care that infants are baptized in the first few weeks; as soon as possible after the birth or even before it, they are to go to the pastor to request the sacrament for their child and to be prepared properly for it.<sup>2</sup>

And CCC 1261 ends by saying, *'All the more urgent is the Church's call not to prevent little children coming to Christ through the gift of holy Baptism.'*

With the backdrop of all these Church teachings and practice, and noting point 52. of Synod 2014 of [*"Relatio post disceptationem"*](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2014/10/13/0751/03037.html)

> 52. Without denying the moral problems associated with homosexual unions, there are instances where mutual assistance to the point of
>       sacrifice is a valuable support in the life of these persons.
>       Furthermore, the Church pays special attention to [...] children who
>       live with same-sex couples and **stresses that the needs and rights of
>       the little ones must always be given priority.**

does the Catholic Church teach that any child, or all children have the "right" to be baptized?

Does the Church teach that anyone has the "right" to be baptized?

If the answer is in the affirmative, who granted those rights?

Please note "Rights" are to be understood as the Church understand them.

<sup>1. cf. VI. THE NECESSITY OF BAPTISM | [Catechism of the Catholic Church, 1257-1261](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm#1256).</sup>
<sup>2. cf. Code of Canon Law [Cann. 867](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P2X.HTM) and [CCC 1250-1252](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm#1249).</sup>

---

Right (Definition noun 18. | Dictionary.com): a just claim or title, whether legal, prescriptive, or moral: *"You have a right to say what you please."*

---

Please see also: [According to Scripture, does anyone born in the world have the right to be baptized?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/according-to-scripture-does-anyone-born-in-the-world-have-the-right-to-be-bapti)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "right," and how that would contrast with a lack of rights to baptism? Are you asking of the Catholic church can refuse baptism to someone who wants it?

Comment: cf. "Rights" as understood by the Church. Perhaps another approach would be from the understanding of "Rights" in the [US Declaration of Independence](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/declaration_transcript.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always helpful and useful to start with definitions

From the "PENNY CATECHISM" under [Grace and Prayer](http://www.catholictreasury.info/catechism/cat13.php)

> **139** What is Grace?
>   Grace is a supernatural gift of God, freely bestowed upon us for our sanctification and salvation.
>
> **140** How must we obtain God's grace?
>   We must obtain God's grace chiefly by prayer and the holy Sacraments.

And From the "PENNY CATECHISM" under [Baptism](http://www.catholictreasury.info/catechism/cat21.php#baptism)

> **256** What is Baptism?
>   Baptism is a Sacrament which cleanses us from original sin, makes us Christians, children of God, and members
>   of the Church.

**Answering**

It readily follows since Baptism is a Sacrament, a means by which we obtain God's grace,  a supernatural [**gift**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gift)<sup>1</sup> of God, **freely** bestowed upon us for our sanctification and salvation, it is not a right but a **gift freely given to be freely and worthily received.**

<sup>1. cf. [gift definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS569US569&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gift%20definition).</sup>